# Parse HTML content in CodeIgniter 4

Tags: php, parsing, html-parsing, codeigniter-4

I'm using Codeigniter 4.

```
$template = 'Hello, {firstname} {lastname}';
$data = [
    'title' => 'Mr',
    'firstname' => '<h1>John</h1>',
    'lastname' => 'Doe'
];

$parser = \Config\Services::parser();
echo $parser->setData($data)->renderString($template);
```

This is producing,

[image]

But adding `htmlspecialchars_decode()` with this is working properly.

`echo htmlspecialchars_decode($parser->setData($data)->renderString($template));`

[image]

My question is, is it the right way? Why I need to add this raw function? Is there any parameter or something for this? This was working in CI3.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `'Hello, <h1>{firstname}</h1> {lastname}'` ?

Comment: @Syscall, I couldn't overcome with this. :(

Answer (score 0):

You just need to skip the escape.

As when using a pseudo variable in template file just put `!` before and after the variable.

So, the variable to have as below:

```php
$template = 'Hello, {!firstname!} {lastname}';
```